# Basic Rails 3 question: How to sort products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by

I have the following models:

```
Product: name, shop_id (foreign key), brand_id (foreign key), price
Shop:    name
Brand:   name
```

The associations are:

```
Product: belongs_to :shop
         belongs_to :brand
Shop:    has_many   :products
         has_many   :brands,   :through => :products
Brand:   has_many   :products
         has_many   :shops,    :through => :products
```

In `ProductsController#list` I would like to get a list of all products sorted by shop name and then by brand name.

I tried to do:

```
@products = Product.order("products.shop.name ASC, products.brand.name ASC")
```

But it doesn't work (I guess because `products.shop.name` does not exist at the database level).

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Austin L is right, but his syntax is a bit old. The new ActiveRecord syntax is much cleaner:

```
@products = Product.includes(:shop, :brand).order("shops.name ASC, brands.name ASC")
```

Comment: You can't believe how much time it took me to find this. Thank you so much! Just as a heads up and so that other people may find this: I was using order(:field_name) and it was working fine in production with sqlite3 but with my webapp hosted in heroku (which uses postgresql) this was wielding me the error `undefined method gsub for :field_name:Symbol`. Using this syntax it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

See this article: http://www.definenull.com/node/8

In your example:

```
@products = Product.find(:all,:include => [:shop, :brand], :order => 'shops.name ASC, brands.name ASC')
```

I haven't tested this code myself so I can't vouch for it 100% but give it a try. If it dosent work try removing the "ASC" and see if that runs.

Comment: That's pretty spot on. I would use `all` rather than `find(:all...` however. I also corrected your example to have the pluralized table names. But it's a good effort.